# Change image source on thumbnail click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm creating something like a gallery when clicking on a thumbnail should load the corresponding big image.

The way I try to do this is the following.

There's an image tag as follows:

```
<img src="gallery/[image name]" id="bigitem" />
```

The thumbnail is as follows:

```
<img src='gallery/thumbs/[image name]' alt='' at='[image name]' onclick='changePicture()' />
```

The thumbnail image name and the big image name is the same and the custom "at" attribute contains the same image name. The changePicture() function is as follows:

```
function changePicture() {
        var at = $(this).attr('at');     // getting the value of the "at" attribute of the thumbnail
        var newpath = 'gallery/'+at;
        $("#bigitem").attr('src', newpath);   // changing the "src" attribute of the big image.
        }
```

However this function does not work. Seems that I can't get the custom attribute value of "this".

Could anybody help me to figure out why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `this` isn't what you think it is; in that context `this` is the `window` object. You need to pass `this` to the onclick function:

```
<img src="gallery/thumbs/[image name]" alt="" 
    at="[image name]" onclick="changePicture(this);" />

function changePicture(image) {
    var at = $(image).attr('at');
    var newpath = 'gallery/' + at;
    $("#bigitem").attr('src', newpath);
}
```

Comment: wow... I'm curious... how does this one work and mine does not? O_o

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src='gallery/thumbs/[image name]' alt='' at='[image name]' onclick='changePicture(this)' />
```

```
function changePicture(obj) {
        var at = $(obj).attr('at');     // getting the value of the "at" attribute of the thumbnail
        var newpath = 'gallery/'+at;
        $("#bigitem").attr('src', newpath);   // changing the "src" attribute of the big image.
        }
```

You need to pass `this` as a parameter.

`this` refers to the caller of the function.  when changePictures is called (without the param passed) `this` refers to the onclick method and not the img element.  By passing `this` as a function parameter, you are passing the actual node (the caller of *onclick*)

Comment: "at" value comes as undefined

Comment: then that is an issue with the implementation... try this instead: `$("#bigitem").attr('src', obj.src.replace(/(^gallery)\/thumbs(.*)/,"$1$2"));`